# I'm getting an undefined string how do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want people to write in my txt file from discord. This is the code right now:

```
client.on("message", msg => {
  const triggerWords = ['ff'];
  const fs = require('fs');
  const args = msg.content.trim().split(/ +/g);

  triggerWords.forEach((word) => {
    if(msg.content.includes(word)) {
      const con = args[1];
      const content = ` ${con}\n`
      fs.appendFile('textart.txt',content,err => {
        if(err) {
          console.error(err)
          return
        }
      })
    }
  })
});
```

This is want I want the output in txt to be:

```
1 joke1
2 joke2
3 joke3
```

But i'm getting an extra blank line after so its this:

```
1 joke1
2 joke2
3 joke3
4
```

How can I code it so the blank line goes away? Have a nice day!

Comment: Temporarily comment out your `if(err)` block so that you get an actual runtime error and can debug it more easily.

Comment: can you pls look at my question again? I made an edit

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what this line does, given you haven't provided much context for your code:

```js
const line=fs.readFileSync('textart.txt', "utf8").split("\n").leh
```

However, this is probably causing your issue -- `.split()` will return an array, and you are attempting to access a nonexistent property `.leh`. I'm not sure what your intention was here, but this will cause your `line` variable to be `undefined`. Did you mean to access `.length`?

In the future try logging your variables to debug problems like this.

Comment: hey I just recoded my code and this is what I got now:

Comment: I edited my question so you can see it there

Comment: I did it right now

Answer (score 0):

Place the `\n` before the string instead:

```js
const content = `\n ${con}`
```